# How to paint inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I have a JPanel inside a Jframe.I want to draw a line inside JPanel, using paint(Graphics g) method. But it is not working. Please Someone help me on this issue. Here is the code.
Thank you all in advance.

```
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JavaGraph {

JPanel myPanel;

public JPanel createPanel()
{

    myPanel=new JPanel();
    myPanel.setLayout(null);
    //myPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
    return myPanel;

}
public static void  display()
{
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JavaGraph j=new JavaGraph();
    frame.add(j.createPanel());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
        public void run()
        {
            display();
        }
            });
}
```

}

Comment: Override `paintComponent()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you would

- override `getPreferredSize` for `JPanel`, otherwise `JPanel` with Java2D only to returns zero `Dimension`
- override `paintComponent()`, more see in [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- read Oracle tutorial [Inintial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

you wouldn't

- `myPanel.setLayout(null);` use Null Layout
- `frame.setSize(400,400);` for `JFrame`, `JPanel` etc, because `JComponents` (`override getPreferredSize`) are designated to returns proper `Dimension` to its contianer, `JFrame.pack(before JFrame.setVisible)` to calculate, determine proper size for container(s) in pixels
- invoke any code to set, change or intialize Swing GUI, after `frame.setVisible(true);` is called

Comment: not, here are bunch of code examples, search in posts tagged  [java+swing+paintcomponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+paintcomponent?sort=frequent&pageSize=15) especially in answers by MadProgrammer or Hovercraft Full Of Eels